# What is the locus of $z^2+\bar{z}^2=2$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have to prove that it's the equation of an equilateral hyperbola

### $$z^2+z^{-2}=2$$

I try this

### $z^2+z^{-2} +2 = 2+2$

### $(z^2+1/z^2 +2 ) = 4$

### $(z+1/z)^2=4$

### $ z+1/z= 2 $

### $ x+yi + 1/(x+yi) = 2 $

### $ ((x+yi)^2+1)/(x+yi)=2$

### $ x^2+2xyi-y^2+1=2x+2yi$

### $ x^2-2x+1 +2xyi -y^2=2yi $

### $(x-1)^2 +2xyi-y^2= 2yi$

I don't know how to end it.

Comment: You also have $(z-1/z)^2=(z^2+1/z^2)-2=2-2=0$.  This gives $z=1/z$, so $z=\pm1$.  This doesn't give you a hyperbola.  Did you mean $z^2+\overline{z^2}=2$ or something?  The equation $z^2+\overline{z^2}=2$ does indeed give you a hyperbola.

Comment: I don't know the exercise in the book is like that xd maybe it's wrong in the book

Comment: Sorry, a  z-equation represents a geometrical locus if the whole equation is real  e.g. $z+\bar z=0,$ represents a line. $z^2+(\bar z)^2=2$ can represent a geometrical locus. But $z^2+z^{-2}$ cannot..

Comment: Sure is that, i'll try to resolve it. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Let $z = x+iy$ to get $x=\frac12(z+\bar z)$,  $y=-\frac i2(z-\bar z)$, and

$$x^2-y^2=\frac14(z+\bar z)^2 + \frac14(z-\bar z)^2 =\frac12(z^2+\bar z^2)= 1$$

which shows that the locus is an equal-axis hyperbola.

Answer (score 3):

The locus of $$z^2+(\bar z)^2=2 \implies (x+iy)^2+(x-iy)^2=2 \implies x^2-y^2=1$$ which is a hyperbola.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** One can rewrite this quickly using polar coordinates: For $z = r e^{i \theta}$, we have
$$2 = z^2 + \bar z^2 = (r e^{i\theta})^2 + (r e^{-i\theta})^2 = r^2 (e^{2 i \theta} + e^{-2 i \theta}) = r^2 \cdot 2 \cos 2 \theta .$$
Now, divide both sides by $2$, apply the double angle identity for $\cos$, and rewrite in terms of the components $x, y$ of $z = x + i y$.

> Doing so gives $$1 = r^2 (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta) = (r \cos \theta)^2 - (r \sin \theta)^2 = x^2 - y^2 .$$